# How to convert date 1110101 which means 1/1/2011 to a date that Tableau can recognize

Tags: date, tableau-api

I have a data set with date format (which according to our IT it's an IBM format) 1110101 which means 1/1/2011, so 1160506 means 5/6/2016. I tried to convert it to date format that tableau can recognize and here's the plan:

Step 1, I create a field called "Date Converted"= Date I have + 19000000
Step 2, I use DATEPARSE to convert it to date by:

DATEPARSE("yyyymmdd",19000000+[Date I have])

But Tableau doesn't accept DATEPARSE and it says it's an unknown syntax. Anyone know's how to correctly convert IBM date format to a date that Tableau can recognize?

Comment: What data source are you connecting to? Some Tableau functions are not available for some data sources (DATEPARSE for SQL Server for example)

Comment: Is your [Date I have] field a string or integer? The "+" operator does different things accordingly. If your data source does not have DateParse(), or MakeDate(), you can always create a string in MM/DD/YYYY format and use the Date() function

Answer (score 0):

My date format

[image]

Change your format in string

[image]

Create custom calculation

```
MID([Date],6,2) + "/" + MID([Date],4,2) + "/" +MID([Date],2,2)
```

[image]

Change your data type to date

[image]

You date will look like this

[image]

Comment: IBM system where the date format is like this 1170302. The first 1 is not used, the 17 is the year, the 03 is the month and the 02 is the day.

Comment: Hi Mehul, thank you very much. I used your method and the calculation gave me no error, however when I tried to drag the new date to the shelf it gave me a pop out window saying "an error occurred while communicating with data source", I checked the detail and it is "[IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0181 - Value in date, time, or timestamp string not valid." Any possible reason why I am getting this error?

Comment: Actually, the 1 is used; it's added to 19 (thus 20). This is important for 20th century dates; 31 Dec 1999 is (with leading 0) 0991231. If somehow IBM i survives into the 22nd century, 15 March 2106 would be 2060315.

Comment: @emma12345 that may be driver problem can you upload screenshot to get better idea ? update your driver from https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers